# Converting openssh public key to ssh2 (RFC 4716) format

Tags: java, openssh

The main question is just that. Parse the `openssh` public key to [`rfc 4716`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4716) format compliant. The only catch though, is that it has to be in **java**.

Using `ssh-keygen`, it is just single line command :

```
ssh-keygen -e -f openssh_key.pub
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any other sources to do so in Java. Even any algorithm or steps necessary for the conversion are not mentioned. All of them revolve around usage of `ssh-keygen` itself. Ofcourse, I can use [`java.exec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) to call the command, but that is the worst case scenario.

---

Example openssh key (Have kept it in code format so as to retain the spaces/new-line as was produced) :

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDwxgE7D3HYLYddNHLMFK8OfpRwwUSgxiB8fbecvkCUEktSpWikvsWTyCnl5p3uSmsGg/F1lwVPXuuVlQ4VZlYqMuEBEMRF9ADdXWWNxjO/Hd7688ow7ocncxl0xKXsH5Fc9GHvE8yfUh94F8Qm9x8M8Uux+XsNEvPG8KI/QUJWndIsHv+m//3nbEEqUTAlzsyY0mjHW/dPORhXcB5WeGH+cBRAhcp5JGKAq26TOsuNY8H+nrlxX6z03xbUN28HHdXv6uKZfpnVpl6tM0khxbh7F+tLYWeUIZ+nYaDBPINv8Mkd6Duqe/GOLtgVUIR76Adijok4w5oaKlTq27xzMurl kaushik@kaushik-HP
```

Parsed using ssh-keygen :

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "2048-bit RSA, converted by kaushik@kaushik-HP from OpenSSH"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDwxgE7D3HYLYddNHLMFK8OfpRwwUSgxiB8fbecvk
CUEktSpWikvsWTyCnl5p3uSmsGg/F1lwVPXuuVlQ4VZlYqMuEBEMRF9ADdXWWNxjO/Hd76
88ow7ocncxl0xKXsH5Fc9GHvE8yfUh94F8Qm9x8M8Uux+XsNEvPG8KI/QUJWndIsHv+m//
3nbEEqUTAlzsyY0mjHW/dPORhXcB5WeGH+cBRAhcp5JGKAq26TOsuNY8H+nrlxX6z03xbU
N28HHdXv6uKZfpnVpl6tM0khxbh7F+tLYWeUIZ+nYaDBPINv8Mkd6Duqe/GOLtgVUIR76A
dijok4w5oaKlTq27xzMurl
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

**UPDATE :** I have created an [implementation of the conversion on gist](https://gist.github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/293e1ab6b1ace6ed9ede7af5aef366d4), for anyone with similar needs.

Comment: Does BouncyCastle offer something, maybe https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/ebddae

Comment: @ScaryWombat : Interesting lead. Worth checking into. I saw the same question in SO for `C#`, so didn't explore further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Base64 data in the two formats is identical -- you don't need to do anything fancy. All you need to do to convert between these formats is add/remove line breaks (at 70 characters) and change the header/trailer.

Note that both formats have a comment -- `kaushik@kaushik-HP` in the OpenSSH key, and the line starting with `Comment:` in the PEM key. Both are completely optional, and don't need to be converted.

Comment: Have been wondering the same for some time now. But wasn't sure. Is this **guaranteed**? I don't want to surprised by some corner case in the future suddenly and find everything failing.

And could you pls expand on what you mean by `add/remove line breaks (at 70 characters)` - the 70 characters especially.

Comment: And you mentioned `Base64`. What happens if the openssh key is not? Sorry, but am pretty new to the standards for SSH, so have to confirm. Is that a possiblity?

Comment: Yes, this is guaranteed. It's inherent to the two formats. The only other "gotcha" I can think of is [options in an `authorized_keys` file](https://serverfault.com/q/142997/15323), which aren't technically part of the key at all.

Comment: Line breaks: you literally just add `\n` every 70 characters when converting to PEM, or remove the newlines to convert to OpenSSH format. It's that simple. You don't need to worry about the fact that the data is Base64; just treat it as a string.

Comment: Ahha. Good to know. I wanted this confirmed by someone other than myself, someone who knows the stuff :D Thank you! I'll wait for sometime before marking as accepted. Maybe something interesting might show up meanwhile.

Comment: Confirmed that it works perfectly, at least up till present use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if I should laugh or cry, because I finally did find the exact functionality that I required, along with many more in the [JSch library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). This was ofcourse after I wrote [my own implementation](https://gist.github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/293e1ab6b1ace6ed9ede7af5aef366d4) for the conversion. Hence my dilemma about the laugh/cry situation. For now though, happy I learnt something new in the process.

A small example of using the [`JSch's KeyPair class`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/KeyPair.html) :

Generate private-public key pair (RSA) :

```
JSch jSch = new JSch();
KeyPair keyPair = KeyPair.genKeyPair(jSch, KeyPair.RSA);

keyPair.writePrivateKey("privateKey"); //store private key in file - 'privateKey'
keyPair.writePublicKey("publicKey");   //store public key in file - 'publickKey'
```

Convert the public key into RFC 4716 format.

```
keyPair.writeSECSHPublicKey("ssh2Key"); //store ssh2 public key in file - 'ssh2Key'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by duskwuff, here is the code I wrote to do the conversion:

```
public String convert(String rsaKey){
    String[] keyParts = rsaKey.split("\\s"); // header + content + comment
    if(keyParts.length < 2 || !keyParts[0].equals("ssh-rsa"))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The key "+rsaKey+" is not a properly formatted RSA key.");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----\n");
    final int rowLength = 70;
    final String keyContent = keyParts[1];
    for(int i=0; i*rowLength < keyContent.length(); i++){
        sb.append(keyContent, i*rowLength, Math.min((i+1)*rowLength, keyContent.length())).append('\n');
    }
    sb.append("---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----");
    return sb.toString();
}
```